Double analogue of the domain functor
For a category $\mathcal{C}$, the domain functor $\mathbf{dom} \colon \mathcal{C}^2 \to \mathcal{C}$ is a fibration.
Denote $\mathbb{D}_1^2$ for the category of proarrows and cells between them and denote $\mathbb{D}_1$ for the category of objects and proarrows.
Q: I am explicitly trying to prove that the projection $\mathbf{dom}^* \colon \mathbb{D}_1^2 \to \mathbb{D}_1 $ is a fibration following definition 2.23 in Double Fibration
I suppose the projection takes an object (proarrow) to its domain object and a cell to its internal domain (see Example 2.9 in Double Fibrations) .
The motivation of the question comes from Example 2.24 in Double Fibrations. What confuses me is that showing that a morphism (a cell in $\mathbb{D}_1^2$) of proarrows is cartesian, is this treatment similar for proving that 2-cells of $\mathcal{C}^2$ are cartesian? I am not famililar with fibrations in which the morphisms in the category are proarrows. Or perhaps there is a different way to prove this?
